# echo trims multiple spaces from a Bash variable

Tags: bash, shell, echo, sh

```
LINE="a    b"
echo $LINE
```

when I run this sh file, I get this output:

```
a b
```

I actually want to process a BAI2 file where spaces and indexes need to be accurate. I loop over each line and `echo $line >> "${FILE}"`. So I need all the spaces in the line to be printed as it is. Please help me what I can do to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

## Quote your variables!

```
echo "$LINE"
```

Otherwise, word splitting is performed and `echo` sees two arguments `a` and `b`, rather than one argument `"a    b"`. Try with `set -x` to see the difference.

Comment: thanks.. it works... wow it is so simple.. :D